# TestNG - Only Priorirty = 1 method is executed

Tags: selenium, testng

I have a testNG.xml file as below:

```
<suite name="example suite 1"  >
 <test name = "exampletest2" preserve-order="true"  >
  <classes>
     <class name = "sprint0.class1" />
     <class name = "sprint0.class2" />
  </classes>
  </test>    
</suite>
```

each class has mutliple test methods where priority is set:
example:class1

```
public class class1 extends TestSetup {
    @Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "TerminateEmpData" , enabled = true )
     public void test1class1 (String searchKey, String ChangedKey) {
         /* code */
       }
   @Test(priority = 2, dataProvider = "TerminateEmpData" , enabled = true )
     public void test2class1 (String searchKey, String ChangedKey) {
        /* code */
       }
   @Test(priority = 3, dataProvider = "TerminateEmpData" , enabled = true )
   public void test3class1 (String searchKey, String ChangedKey) {
      /* code */
      }
   }
```

Another class2 as below:

```
    public class class2 extends TestSetup {
    @Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "TerminateEmpData" , enabled = true )
     public void test1class2 (String searchKey, String ChangedKey) {
         /* code */
       }
   @Test(priority = 2, dataProvider = "TerminateEmpData" , enabled = true )
     public void test2class2 (String searchKey, String ChangedKey) {
        /* code */
       }
   }
```

After I run above testng.xml file, only method with Priority =1 is execueted.

I would like to understand what am i doing wrong here?

Also I would like to mention in TestSetup class,
**@BeforeMethod, I invoke the browser and login to the application

and

@AfterMethod, I do teardown and take screenshot for test failure.**

***I would like to understand what am i doing wrong here as I am not able to get all my methods run.***

An alternative which i created is to create a testsuite for individual class and then call all the test suits and run in seperate testng.xml which works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi,
I don't see something wrong, can you share us the TestNG version you are using? and let me know what will be the output if you add group-by-instances="true" to your xml

Comment: Hello Nael, I am using v 6.14.3 of the TesNG. Also I tried the group-by-instances="true" but  still face the same issue where only method with Priority = 1 is executed.

Comment: What if you let priority start from 0 to 2? and the none executed tests are skipped or never run?